# keystone.js API and cloudinary image upload

Tags: node.js, api, cloudinary, keystonejs

I have a keystone installation mostly used as API resource for mobile app as front-end. When I take a photo with phone I would like to save photo to cloudinary service. Photo is sent to server as base64 string. Can I upload image on cloudinary service using some keystone api or I have to use cloudinary module methods to do it and manually insert data to db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed upload images to your Cloudinary account via Keystone's service. See:
http://keystonejs.com/docs/configuration/#services-cloudinary.

You can also have a look at Keystone's demo:
https://github.com/JedWatson/keystone-demo